# data are stored as null in java jersey web service

Tags: java, json, web-services, post, jersey

Hi i am created web service using java jersey.I am using query param.But if I pass the paramaters the data final result is stored as an null value.

```
here is my code.

@Path("/val")
public class RESTservice {
@POST
@Path("/store")
public Response getMsg(
@QueryParam("city") final String city,
@QueryParam("locality")final String locality)
StoreIntoHDFS obj = new StoreIntoHDFS(city,locality);
String response1 = obj.storeAddress();
return Response.status(200).entity(response1.toString()).build();
}
}

JSON Structure

data - > array
{ 
  page_1 
        {
         parameters
        }
 }
}
```

The datas are in null value.any help will be appreciated.